# compilacion fallida al instalar otro plugin cordova (Launch Navigator) a mi proyecto ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic, cordova

espero esten bien.
Tengo el siguiente error:

Tengo una serie de cosas ya instaladas em mi proyecto ionic, al correr el siguiente comando ionic cordova run android -l la compilacion es exitosa y la app funciona perfectamente.
Sin embargo, al instalar otro plugin, en este caso Launch Navigator, la app compila exitosamente, pero al interactuar con la app se cierra y se detiene la compilacion.
Ya investigue y no he encontrado nada, nose si a alguien mas le pasa, ayuda por favor. A continuación les dejo el package.json del proyecto para que vean las instalaciones que tengo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en las imagenes esta subrayado los lugares donde esta el launch navigator.

muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar utilizando una version anterior del plugin nativo.

Primero desinstala el plugin

```
npm uninstall @ionic-native/launch-navigator
```

y prueba con esta version que es la que actualmente uso en proyectos de ionic 4

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/launch-navigator@5.22.0
```

En caso que te falle desinstalar el tambien al plugin de cordova, he instala esta version

```
cordova plugin remove uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator
ionic cordova plugin add uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator@5.0.4
```

Si todavia no funciona, por favor muestrame como lo estas importando a tus componentes.

Comment: gracias, me sirvio excelente recomendacion